# Is it safe to delete replication relay-bin files?

Tags: mysql, replication

I've got a small database, around 50mb. It's a master replicating to a remote server. I noticed that the relay-bin files total to over 5GB. Is it safe to delete them?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

No, do not delete the relay-bin files manually. What you can do is to purge the binary files using MySQL commands. See the [MySQL 5.0 Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/purge-binary-logs.html) for more on the `PURGE BINARY LOGS` command.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i needed? Will purge ensure that replication is not affected?

Comment: Yes, replication will not be affected at any time.

Comment: Can these files be deleted if replication has been turned off and won't be used again?

Comment: "PURGE BINARY LOGS" only related to binary logs, not relay logs

Comment: This does something different as it wask asked, that might harm your mariadb setup. The proper answer is Rodo's.

Answer (score 37):

I think a better answer is relay logs can be 'deleted' but mysql should manage it automatically.
One way to do this is to check for the value of relay_log_purge.

It should be set to 1 if you want mysql to manage them:

```
set global relay_log_purge=1;
```

You would probably need to flush the logs:

```
flush logs;
```

This does not affect the binary logs.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMO. We just found a server that had apparently had relay_log_purge turned off manually several months ago and had been steadily filling up its disk with relay logs. Running these commands worked perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe try to resync your master and slave.

If possible, cleanup the slave by running a

`reset slave`

it will purge all relay binary logs.

Then set the replication again with `change master to` ...
You may have too much lag between your master and slave.

Comment: Worked where the other suggestions didn't

Answer (score 0):

From the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slave-logs-relaylog.html):

> The SQL thread automatically deletes each relay log file after it has
>   executed all events in the file and no longer needs it. There is no
>   explicit mechanism for deleting relay logs because the SQL thread
>   takes care of doing so. However, FLUSH LOGS rotates relay logs, which
>   influences when the SQL thread deletes them.